# How to use the global variable in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
    <?php
    class chargemen extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

    public $jobs_session=array(); 

    public function set_jobs($array)
    {
    $this->jobs_session=$array;
    }
    public function get_jobs()
    {
    return $this->jobs_session; //when i'm acessing this functions it returns null array
    }
    public function form()
    {
    $a=$this->input->post();
    $this->set_jobs($a); 
}

  ?>
```

Is it possible to acess global variables in ci, i'm tryng to access it, but it returns `null array`.can u plz help me to acess it or suggest a best way to keep the data without using sessions n cookies

Comment: A better question is "Should I be using global variables?"  And the answer is an emphatic no.

Comment: If only there _were_ a global variable. I just see a public class property

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, you just have to call function where your set_jobs action is called.

In your case it is form() which I have called in my index function.

```
$this->form();
$res = $this->get_jobs(); 
print_r($res);
```

I have tested with following code in my controller

```
public function index()
{
     $this->form();
     $res = $this->get_jobs(); 
     print_r($res);
}


public $jobs_session=array(); 

public function set_jobs($array)
{
    $this->jobs_session=$array;
}
public function get_jobs()
{
    return $this->jobs_session; //when i'm acessing this functions it returns null array
}
public function form()
{    
    $a = array('1','2','3');
    //$a=$this->input->post();
    $this->set_jobs($a); 
}
```

**Please note that, you won't be able to access this methods outside of the scope of this controller.**

Comment: As you said when i call the form(), before calling the get_jobs() there is an error occured.i had loaded a view in form().and i'm accessing the get_jobs() in form2().now two times the views are going to display because form() having a view & form2() also having its own view.then how to overcome from this problem..

Comment: Well I don't see anything related to view here so I'm not sure what you are trying to do? Solution given is purely based on codeblock you have provided in question. which seems working good. What other things you are trying apart of this?